# Showing float numbers Grails in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to manipulate float numbers in gsp, here is what i want:

If the number has a 1.* i want it to show the dot, but if it ends with zero i dont want it to show the dot and zero.

like this:

Score: 1.5

Score: 1

Score: 2.1

Score: 3

The score variable is a float number and it is an input field on the gsp that loads the number and it can be changed.

But the real problem is, how can i see if the number has decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a taglib for formating numbers:  (g:formatNumber)

I think something like this should work:

```
<g:formatNumber number="${score}" type="number" format="###.##"/>
```

But...if that doesn't work...

I would say write your own custom taglib.  If it is something that is going to be used multiple times, why loop through a list of objects in your controller, change the float to a string just to display it?  Let the page decide how to show it in the proper context.

Or

Add a transient field to the domain object (String scoreDisplay) and then have getScoreDisplay() return the value of score as a string, formatted how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest you to format the number in your controller - before it gets to your gsp. That way you have more control over the number format. Once you're in the gsp, you have to use a grails' decimal number format or [make your own taglib](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.3.6%20Using%20JSP%20Tag%20Libraries) to format (since the number of fractional digits changes in your case).